# Generate hmacSha1 signature in node.js same as java?

Tags: java, node.js, cryptography

That is how i am generating hmacsha1 signature in java

```
private static byte[] hmac_sha1(String crypto, byte[] keyBytes, byte[] text) {
Mac hmac = null;

    try {
        hmac = Mac.getInstance(crypto);
        SecretKeySpec macKey =
            new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "RAW");
        hmac.init(macKey);
        System.out.println("hmac: "+Arrays.toString(keyBytes));
        return hmac.doFinal(text);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // NOTE. Deviation from reference code.
    // Reference code prints a stack trace here, which is not what we
    // want in a production environment, so instead we rethrow.
    throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(e);
    }

}
```

I need help to generate same in node.js. Can someone please help me on this? As people mentioned that I need to show what I have tried here is the code that I have written in node.js to create a same functionality

```
Ocra.hmacSha1 = function(crypto, keyBytes, text) {
    var digest, hmac;
    hmac = nodeCrypto.createHmac(crypto, new Buffer(keyBytes, 'utf8'));
    console.log(this.bin2String(keyBytes));
    digest = hmac.update(new Buffer(text, 'utf8')).digest('hex');        
    return this.hexStr2Bytes(digest);    // here i am converting string into bytes array    
};
```

The above code is not producing the desired results. If I pass these parameters to java code
crypto: sha1
keyBytes: [ 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 48 ]
text:79678265454958727984804583726549455458817848560000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

they produce different result and in node.js it produces different results.

Note: In java crypto is HmacSHA1 and text is in form of array not string as you can see in code as well.

Comment: See the docs, it's easy: http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createhmac_algorithm_key

Comment: Not the best question without showing what has been tried, but it definitely is not "off topic".

Comment: @owlstead At the time I voted to close it ***was*** off topic, through failing to "demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved", including no evidence of what has been tried. This has now changed due to the latest edit. I vote fairly, but early, due to the myriad of questions that never improve.

Answer (score 0):

What are you passing as `keyBytes` in the JavaScript version? `new Buffer(keyBytes, 'utf8')` is almost certainly not what you want. If you're passing a hex encoded string, you need to hex decode it: `new Buffer(keyBytes, 'hex')`. If you're passing an array, you have to do `new Buffer(keyBytes)`.

Comment: I am passing array [ 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 48 ] as keyBytes. Which is a hexadecimal representation of OCRA-1:HOTP-SHA1-6:QN08

Comment: In that case, according to the documentation, `new Buffer(keyBytes)` should do the trick.

Comment: If I try the solution you have mentioned above
hmac = nodeCrypto.createHmac(crypto, new Buffer(keyBytes));
        console.log(new Buffer(keyBytes));
I get empty hmac.